# Removing a option from select in javascript using id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a dropdown of 5 values. I just want to remove only one option from it.

```
<select id="xyz" > 
<option id='one'>1</option>
<option id='two'>2</option>
<option id='three'>3</option>
</select>
```

I tried something like this

```
if(something){
  $("#two").remove();
}
```

But this does not work. I also tried .hide() and that didn't work either.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: For future reference, Java is something else entirely. Please don't use that tag when you mean javascript.

Comment: Back to your problem, are you sure the problem is not with `if(something)` instead?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i added that if statement just for understanding purpose only. It's not real code.

Comment: Yeah, that's clear, but I meant that there's nothing wrong with `$("#two").remove();` (of course assuming you correctly imported jquery and you don't have any other error the breaks the script somewhere else) so the problem must be elsewhere, for example in `if (something)`, whatever `something` is may be false. If, instead you don't have an `if` at all please remove it from the example, it's only confusing.